# How to view full data when using Dataframe in pandas while using jupyternotebook?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

rather than having the ....(dot dot) view when opening a data frame, how to access or see all the values in Jupyter notebook. [reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcWXO.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

You can set "display.max_rows" option in pandas:  `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)` or `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', LARGE_NUMBER)`

To set it temporarily use a context manager:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None):
    print(df)
```